# submit two form contents onto one action page

Tags: javascript

i have two Forms to be submitted to a single destination page.

```
<form name= "form1" id="form1" action="final.php">
<input type="box1" name="box1" value="" >
</form>

<form name ="form2" id="form2" action="final.php">
<table>
<input type ="text" id="txt_1"  name ="txt_1" value="">

 ...


</table>
</form>

<input type= "button" name="mybutton" id="mybutton" onclick="somefunction();">
```

here ,

form1 has some satic contents

and

form2 has a table which is dynamically generated by js...
problem is ...i want to submitted values from both the forms to same page final.php ...how cud i do it .....pls avoid jquery/ajax...
simple javascript welcomed ...

thanks in advance !

---

this is the js for generating dynamic table in form2

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function viewsource() {
alert(document.body.innerHTML);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function addRowToTable()
{
   var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
   var frm=document.form2;
   if (!frm.ary) frm.ary=[frm.t1_1,frm.t1_2,frm.t1_3];
   var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
   // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);



   // numberd row
    var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
    cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

    // Item row
     var cellRight1 = row.insertCell(1);
     var el1 = document.createElement('input');
     frm.ary.push(el1);
     el1.type = 'text';
     el1.value = '';
     el1.name = 't' + iteration + '_1';
     el1.id = 't' + iteration + '_1';
     el1.size = 13;
     el1.onkeyup=Calc;
     el1.onblur=Calc;
     cellRight1.appendChild(el1);

  // Price row
    var cellRight2 = row.insertCell(2);
       var el2 = document.createElement('input');
    frm.ary.push(el2);
     el2.type = 'text';
     el2.value = '';
    el2.name = 't' + iteration + '_2';
    el2.id = 't' + iteration + '_2';
    el2.size = 10;
    el2.onkeyup=Calc;
    el2.onblur=Calc;
    cellRight2.appendChild(el2);

    // Price row
    var cellRight3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var el3 = document.createElement('input');
    frm.ary.push(el3);
    el3.type = 'text';
    el3.value = '0';
    el3.name = 't' + iteration + '_3';
    el3.id = 't' + iteration + '_3';
    el3.size = 10;
    cellRight3.appendChild(el3);

  }

  function removeRowFromTable()
  {
      var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
     if (lastRow > 3) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
  }

   function formReset()
    {
      document.getElementById("form2").reset();
     }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">


    function Calc(){
   var frm=document.form2;
    if (!frm.ary){ frm.ary=[frm.t1_1,frm.t1_2,frm.t1_3];}
       for (var zxc0=0;zxc0<frm.ary.length;zxc0+=3)
     {
      var total =1;
     if (frm.ary[zxc0].value.length>0&&!isNaN(frm.ary[zxc0].value)) 
     { 
     total =frm.ary[zxc0].value*1* frm.ary[zxc0+1].value;
     }
      frm.ary[zxc0+2].value =total;

      }
     var sum1 =0;
     for (var zxd0=0;zxd0<frm.ary.length;zxd0+=3)
     {
       if (frm.ary[zxd0+2].value.length>0&&!isNaN(frm.ary[zxd0+2].value)) 
    { 
    sum1 +=parseInt(frm.ary[zxd0+2].value);
       }
      }
      frm.sum.value = sum1;
     }


    </script>


   <form action="final.php" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
    <imput type ="text" name ="temp" id="temp" >
   <table border="2"  border-color="#000000" border-type="solid" id="tblSample"            
   align="center" font-size="20">
    <tr>
    <th>
     <input type="button" value="Add " onclick="addRowToTable();"></th><th>
     <input  type="button" value="Remove " onclick="removeRowFromTable();" /></th>
    <th> <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="formReset();">
   </th>

    </tr><br>

      <tr id="cloneid" >
         <td>
         1.
       </td>
        <td>
    <input type="text" name="t1_1" id="t1_1" size="16" value="0" onkeyup="Calc();"   
      onblur="Calc();">
      </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="t1_2" id="t1_2" size="16" value="0" onkeyup="Calc();"    
     onblur="Calc();">
     </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="t1_3" id="t1_3" value= "0" size="16">
       </td>

   </tr>
      </table>
    <table border="2" border-color="#000000" align="center">
 <tr>
   <td colspan="3" align="center">
  Sum: <input type="text" name="sum" id="sum">
  </td>

   </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

 <input type="button" name = "mybutton" id ="mybutton"  value="set"  
     onclick="somefunction();">

     }
```

and

form1 is same as mentioned including jquery for datetimepickers along witha  couple of text boxes...

Comment: merge form 2 into form 1

Comment: Nikhil, simply delete: `</form><form name ="form2" id="form2" action="final.php">` and submit only the `form1`. Or do you have some another obstacles?

Comment: merge them and use div for the dynamic content..

Comment: But when i am using one form then the java script functionality become inactive which is for dynamic row creation

Comment: So then update your question with the code you use for generating the second table and form. It's surely simple to update it to make it functional (either with .appendChild, .insertBefore, .createElement, etc., or via jquery). Both forms cannot be submitted independently, [they don't merge](http://pastebin.com/Hg381wKB).

Comment: hey stano, i have updated the cod..kindly see and provide a remedy for the issue ..

Answer (score 0):

u can use Java Script

```
function button1click() {
  yourForm.action = "Final.php";
  yourForm.submit();
}
```

n in HTML

```
<form action='' method='post'>
  ..
</form>
```

Comment: u can add other form and its JS function in the same way. whenever a form will be submitted, it will be posted in that page